# Trouble with strings in C

Tags: c, string

I'm newbie in C world and I have two probably stupid questions.

I'm reading about structures in C and here is where I stuck. Let say we have structure like this

```
typedef structs {
  char model[50];
  int yearOfManufacture;
  int price;
} Car;

Car Ford;
Ford.yearOfManufacture = 1997;
Ford.price = 3000;

//The line below gives me an error "Array type char[50] is not assignable
Ford.model = "Focus"
```

How to pass text into Ford.model in that case ?

My second question is also about strings.
This code works fine

```
char model[50] = "Focus";
printf("Model is %s", model);
```

But this one doesn't

```
char model[50];
model = "Focus";
```

Can anyone explain why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with structs; it's the same question about strings twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you copy strings in C. Try

```
strcpy(Ford.model, "Focus");
```

Alternatively (but with **[very different semantics](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html)**):

```
typedef structs {
  char const *model;
  int yearOfManufacture;
  int price;
} Car;

model = "Focus";
```

These C FAQs explain more about the issue:

- [Assign to array](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html)
- [How can an array be an lvalue, if you can't assign to it?](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arraylval.html)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to "put values in objects":

- with initialization, when the object is created
- with assignment, after the object is created

Though the syntax is similar, they represent different concepts.

You can initialize an array, but you cannot assign to it.

Also there's a special construct to initialize `char` arrays based on string literals

```
char arr[] = "foobar";
char arr[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', '\0'};
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
// ...
```

but, assignement must be done element by element

```
char arr[4];
arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = 'X';
arr[3] = '\0';
int arr[4];
arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = 42;
arr[3] = -1;
```

---

A "special" way to assign elements of a `char` arrays one-by-one with a single statement is to use the library function `strcpy()` with prototype in `<string.h>`

```
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    char arr[10];
    strcpy(arr, "foo"); // same as arr[0]='f'; arr[1]=arr[2]='o'; arr[3]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This (`Ford.model = "Focus"`) is not possible. You have to copy the string into the array in the struct, best with `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(Ford.model, "Focus");
```

If your stdlib supports it, you should also consider an overflow safe version, e.g `strncpy`:

```
strncpy(Ford.model, "Focus", sizeof Ford.model);
```

At least I think its an extension function and not in the standard... I'm not sure.

Comment: It's standard, but C99 standard, which not every platform supports. On Win32 they have it, but named `_snprintf` or `sprintf_s`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to a character array with `=`, you can only initialize it.

When you write

```
char model[50] = "Focus";
```

that is a initialization.

When you write

```
model = ...
```

that is an assignment. And, as I said, assignment to character arrays is not allowed.

You need to copy to the character array using `strcpy()`, e.g. `strcpy(model, "Focus")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a string during definition, but anywhere else you have to use a different method, like the `strcpy()` function:

```
char model[50];
strcpy(model, "Focus");
```

Comment: You can **initialize** during *definition*, not declaration. Often they (declaration and definition) happen at the same time, but you can have declarations separate from definition.